# NextJS application uploaded on Vercel not fetching updated record

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have created a demo meetup NextJS application and deployed it on Vercel. It works perfectly fine on localhost and on Vercel server as well.

But problem I am facing is that I am not able to fetch the latest record from the MongoDB database.

Let me explain with the example: I have a form which is used to upload/insert the data on MongoDB collection. It is inserting properly on DB and after inserting on the client side (NextJS side) I am redirecting to the home page where I am fetching data from MongoDB using "getStaticProps".

On home page after redirecting I am not able to see latest inserted record. I have to do some changes on the code and need to push it and after doing redeployment it is showing me the latest record. I guess this is not the right way to achieve latest record.

Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Hey there can you show some screen shots so i can see what really happens

Comment: if you'll push your code to GitHub then vercel will automatically re-deploy your app

Comment: @zainuldin screenshot regarding what? I am not getting the latest inserted record from mongodb database on the vercel but it is showing perfectly on the localhost.

Comment: please check changes happen in your repo or not?

Comment: Yes. Changes are there in repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `getStaticProps`, which generates your HTML structure on build. This way, your app is not updating its data whenever they change. It works locally in `development` mode because `getStaticProps` is "disabled" in this mode (it runs on every request, essentailly becoming `getServerSideProps`). Try using `getServerSideProps` instead.

Comment: Oh! Yes. By using getserversideprops it worked. Thank you